# OkHttp in android for making network requests

Tags: java, android, okhttp

**What I am trying to do**::

I am trying to learn the usage of [***Okhttp***](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)  for making networking calls in android

---

**What I have done**::

- I have read their documentation [***here***](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
- I have downloaded and added the JAR in the project
- I am using their sample code from [***here***](https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/guide/GetExample.java)

---

**MyCode**::

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Response;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md")
                .build();

            Response response = client.execute(request);

            Log.d("ANSWER", response.body().string());

        }

    }
```

---

**Error i am facing**::

In the line `Response response = client.execute(request);`
I am getting error as :

> client cannot resolved to a variable

How to resolve this !

---

### {Update}

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md")
            .build();

        Response response = client.execute(request);

        Log.d("ANSWER", response.body().string());

    }

}
```

Now I am facing error as :

> in the line `Response response = client.execute(request);` as `The method execute(Request) is undefined for the type OkHttpClient`

Comment: The code on `master` does not correspond to the latest release.

Comment: @ jake Wharton .... I don't understand .... Can u point me to a vaild code(or post the changes on my code as answer) ..... I tried to find example but there are no much resource availabe in i could get hold of , Thanks

Comment: He means the master branch is not the same as the 1.5.4 release.  Check https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-1.5.4/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/guide/GetExample.java for the 1.5.4 sample of a GET request.

Comment: Just a note: I fixed a similar issue with a simple `gradle clean --refresh-dependencies` .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The method execute(Request) is undefined for the type OkHttpClient

You are getting this exception because there is no such method ie.`execute(Request`) for `OkHttpClient`. Rather it is invoked on `Call` object which is obtained using `OkHttpClient` object as follows:

```
  Call call = client.newCall(request);
  Response response = call.execute();
```

I think you should be using

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

instead of `Response response = client.execute(request);`

[OkHttp docs](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

[OkHttp Blog](http://corner.squareup.com/2014/06/okhttp-2.html)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use the new 2.0 RC of okHttp.

To make a POST petition, the best is :

```
String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> (){

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                client = new OkHttpClient();
                s = post("https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md","");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e("ANSWER", "" + s);

        }
    }.execute();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... ulr) {
    Response response = null;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(ulr[0])
    .build();

    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
         return response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;        
}
```

use like this!

Answer (score 1):

you are missing this line

`OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding internet permissions in your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need declare client variable like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
```

Also you should use your request using some thread or AsyncTask!

You can read something else about AsyncTask on Android in this link: http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Comment: I tried with thread and async task still same error ase shown in update persists .... Am i missing something else here ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to replace:
**This:**

```
Response response = client.execute(request);
```

**By:**

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```