# okhttp3 fail to request for android project

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am using `okhttp`, for my Android project. All the requirements work good but when I need to **call a request** for a **client** it will show the error below:

```
> The method newCall(Request) is undefined for the type OkHttpClient
```

I need to create a call like this:

`Call call = client.newCall(request);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OkHttp in android for making network requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201663/okhttp-in-android-for-making-network-requests)

Comment: but my problem is different

Comment: It would be good if you could add more context to your question. Like Gradle section where you have OkHttp libraries included, as well as minimal code (with imports, declarations..) that exhibits above behavior.

Comment: `Call call = client.newCall(request);` works fine with OkHttp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check which version of `OkHttpClient` are you already using. 
As Jake Wharton states: `newApi()` is reserved only for newest `2.x` version. 
Please take a look at: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/814

Please upgrade your `OkHttpClient` to latest version. Put into Gradle file

```
      compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

Then, in your activity import:

```
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
```

Hope it help

Comment: but the problem is the method newCall() is not in the class so how should i execute that?
and my okhttp version is 3.1

Comment: I think that passing value by constructor between classes would make it

Comment: can u please give me link to the 2.x version?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have correct import classes listed, and that you are not mixing old classes with new ones.

```
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
```