# POST with contentType application/json to Android AsyncHttpServer sets request body to null

Tags: android, json, curl, jackson, androidasync-koush

I have [AsyncHttpServer](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) working on my Android device. I have reqquest callback method for POST set like this:

```
server.post(pattern, new HttpServerRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRequest(AsyncHttpServerRequest request, 
                              AsyncHttpServerResponse response) {
            try {
                List<T> entityList = mapper.readValue(request.getBody().get().
                                     toString(), typeReference);
                for (T newEntity : entityList) {
                    newEntity.save();
                }
                response.code(200);
                response.end();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

where server is `new AsyncHttpServer()`, and mapper is `new ObjectMapper()`

I have breakpoint at line starting with `List<T>`, and I am trying to POST some data to server with cURL like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '[{"_id":"767da7ae-
7826-4f67-853a-23f1d69b5f39","label":"L"}]' http://myserver:5000/test
```

For some reason, when I am posting with `Content-Type` set to `application/json` `request.getBody()` returns `null`, but if I change content type to `text/plain` body contains JSON data set with cURL as I would expect it to.

Does anyone knows why this happens, and how can I make it work with `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: you might read through https://teamtreehouse.com/community/new-callback-wants-to-be-implemented-differently and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24550565/1815624

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was using Volley library. The problem have become solved by using :

> "application/json; charset=utf-8";

as the body content type.